# How to know the current block reward in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

How to know the block reward value for a Particular block . Like the block reward has decreased from 5 to 3 to 2 ether now. So if i an given a block number what is the formula to calculate the block reward

Answer (score 1):

[Note that this answer addresses the *static* block reward, and ignores both transaction fees paid to miners, and uncle rewards.]

> So if i an given a block number what is the formula to calculate the block reward

**For blocks 0 -> 4,369,999 the reward was 5 ETH.**

During the Byzantium hard fork (Oct 2017) [EIP-649](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/669) reduced the reward from 5 to 3.

**For blocks 4,370,000 -> 7,279,999 the reward was 3 ETH.**

During the Constantinople hard fork (Feb 2019) [EIP-1234](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1234.md) reduced the reward from 3 to 2.

**For blocks 7,280,000 onward the reward is 2 ETH.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula to calculate block rewards. The change in block rewards take place by virtue of hard forks. In the new fork, along with other things, the block rewards can be adjusted. These adjustments are discussed by the ethereum community via [Ethereum Improvement Proposals](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs).

Read [this](https://medium.com/nuo-news/istanbul-hard-fork-everything-you-need-to-know-about-it-3a29738934e5) article about forks

Also block reward is a property of the block which means miner sets it to a particular value which will be generally the fixed reward for the block and the transaction fees for the block. Any other node that receives this block will validate the block reward as a part of block validation.

You can read about block creation and validation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#blockchain-and-mining)

To see the reward for a particular block you can visit [here](https://etherscan.io/block/8624214). I have searched for the latest block at the time of writing as an example.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay , Could you let me know if the block reward remains fixed for certain period of time like till any fork happened

Comment: yes. the fixed portion will be fixed for one fork. However there is still the transaction fees that can change per block.